# Has Riiya or Shiine ever performed a Magical Boy Transformation?

Tags: akazukin-chacha

So far, I have only seen Chacha's [Magical Girl Transformation](http://chacha.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Princess), but I haven't seen the counterpart of that for boys from either Riiya (リーヤ) or Shiine (しいね).

[image][image]

From what I remember, Riiya and Shiine did transform into magical animals/items to help Chacha fight against the villains. I have forgotten the storyline in every episode, so I wonder if it's ever shown in the anime that Riiya and/or Shiine transformed into a magical human form like the Magical Princess?

[image]

Comment: Human Form ? they are already in human form in that picture . Maybe a tools ?

Comment: I mean, Magical Human Form like Chacha?

Answer (score 1):

You could base it on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akazukin_Chacha#Main_characters).

If I remember correctly, they don't have any HUMAN MAGICAL TRANSFORMATION, unlike Chacha.

Riiya transforms into a strong wolf that is sometimes mistaken as a DOG. He doesn't have any human magical transformation.

[image: l]

And for Shine, a fellow wizard apprentice who is adept at casting spells and barriers, as well as transformations, his power is better than Chacha's. But I don't remember him being transformed into someone like Chacha's magical human form, the Magical Princess.

[image: T]